# Words being cut off when text mining

Tags: r

I am doing some text mining and am doing a simple list of most frequent words. I am removing stop words as well as some other tidying of data. Here is the corpus along with the matrix and sorting:

```
# Preliminary corpus
corpusNR <- Corpus(VectorSource(nat_registry)) %>%
  tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
  tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
  tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
  tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english")) %>%
  tm_map(stripWhitespace) %>%
  tm_map(stemDocument)

# Create term-document matrices & remove sparse terms
tdmNR <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpusNR) %>%
  removeSparseTerms(1 - (5/length(corpusNR)))

# Calculate and sort by word frequencies
word.freqNR <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(tdmNR)), 
                     decreasing = T)

# Create frequency table
tableNR <- data.frame(word = names(word.freqNR), 
                       absolute.frequency = word.freqNR, 
                       relative.frequency = 
                         word.freqNR/length(word.freqNR))

# Remove the words from the row names
rownames(tableNR) <- NULL

# Show the 10 most common words
head(tableNR, 10)
```

Here are the top ten words I am ending up with:

```
> head(tableNR, 10)
        word absolute.frequency relative.frequency
1     vaccin                 95          0.4822335
2    program                 82          0.4162437
3      covid                 59          0.2994924
4     health                 59          0.2994924
5       educ                 55          0.2791878
6     extens                 53          0.2690355
7     inform                 49          0.2487310
8  communiti                 42          0.2131980
9     provid                 41          0.2081218
10    counti                 36          0.1827411
```

Notice a portion of many of the words is being cut off #1 should be "vaccine", #5 should be "education"...ect.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are running `stemDocument` which trims off the ends of words to make it easier to collapse related words. If you don't want that, then don't run that step.

Comment: Perfect! If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it.